# how's map returning datavalues as plain object here, when datavalues are not object?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

While retrieving data from mysql through sequelize, it was returning datavalues instead of a JSON object.

I tried a trick,

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))` to make it an object.

But then I've found

`result.map(el => el.get({ plain: true }))`
I knew map works with objects.

What my question is how map works with datavalues?

Comment: map is an Array method - so, map doesn't do what you think you want it to do

Comment: can you share your datavalues?

Comment: I agree Jaromanda X. It is what I am getting looks like Afaq Ahmed Khan. Could anyone of you please elaborate what the code `result.map(el => el.get({ plain: true }))` is doing with this: `{
    dataValues:
     {
      ....
    _previousDataValues:
     {      .....
    _changed: {},
    _modelOptions:
     { .... },
    _options:
     { .... },
    __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
    isNewRecord: false }`